# Backup of Xen servers and laptops with encryption

Tags: windows, backup, xen

I have the following backup objects:

- Multiple Xen Linux instances running on same box.
- A few laptops Windows that contain also private data that needs to be stored encrypted

I have this backup media:

- A disk attached to the Xen box
- A disk available remotely for off-site backups

I want to do daily-weekly-monthly backups of Xen systems and to back-up laptops in approximately same mode but in push mode (backup initiated by laptop) with encryption.

Any good free solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. pause domU if backing up xen domU
2. take lvm snapshot of domU's LV (or the LV the images lies on
3. backup with dirvish over ssh

   - push when backing up a laptop
   - pull via dom0 when backing up xen domUs
4. save those backup in an encrypted container / partition
5. make sure the (password-less) keys for ssh+dirvish atre only allowed to run dirvish on the remote side or what ever else is needed (-< post-client-script e.g.)

All should be trivial to implement with cron and a scripting language of your choise ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked "[Bacula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacula)" ?

rather, see list of backup software free and paid with features [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software)

Comment: I did. It seemed to be quite fine except that it can't really accept push-style backups or work over unreliable links :(